# Check if component is either type

Tags: delphi

I am trying to check if a component is type `TMachine` or `TLabel`  if so i want it to free it as long as its NOT Label1 or label2

but it will not let me do an `OR`  on `if Components[I] is (TMachine) or (TLabel) then` Any way to fix this?

```
    procedure TfDeptLayout.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
     for I := ComponentCount -1 downto 0 do
      begin
          if Components[I] is (TMachine) or (TLabel) then
              if Components[I].Name <> Label2.Name then
                if Components[I].Name <> label3.Name then
                  components[I].Free;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Use if ((Components[I] is (TMachine)) or (Components[I] is (TLabel))) then

Comment: What happens if you change the brackets - "if components[i] is (tmachine or tlabel)" ?

Comment: top one worked!, Second one still gave error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `or` in that way, you need to "repeat" the `is` as well.

You also don't need to use Components[I].Name, it suffices to simpy compare the Components[I] reference with the Label1 and Label2 references:

```
procedure TfDeptLayout.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
     for I := ComponentCount -1 downto 0 do
     begin
       if (Components[I] is TMachine) or (Components[I] is TLabel) then
         if Components[I] <> Label2 then
           if Components[I] <> label3 then
             components[I].Free;
      end;
end;
```

it would also be possible (but maybe less readable) to combine all of the conditionals:

```
procedure TfDeptLayout.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  I: Integer;
  comp: TComponent;
begin
     for I := ComponentCount -1 downto 0 do
     begin
       Comp := Components[I];
       if (Comp is TMachine) then
         Comp.Free
       else if (Comp is TLabel) and (Comp <> Label2) and (Comp <> Label3) then
         Comp.Free;
     end;
end;
```

As an aside, it is best to give components that are referred to in code a meaningful name, rather than using the default Label1, Label2... names

Comment: thanks, used label1 / label2 above, so it was easer to answer question knowing what lable1 is ... instead of calling it mnAsset

Comment: @GlenMorse: Even for us it is easier to distinguish mnAsset and mnTool than label1 and label2. Plus if you don't modify your code before posting you have a better chance of us spotting any problems that may otherwise be lost in the modification.